# 7 white balls and 3 black balls in a box. You take out in sequence 3 balls at random without replacement. Probability that all 3 balls are black?

Tags: probability-theory

What i did was say that the probability the first ball is black is 3/10, then since we removed one the probability the second is black is 2/9 and third is ⅛. So then the probability all three are black is 3/10 + 2/9 + ⅛?

Comment: You have to multiply the probabilities, not add them.

Comment: Suppose that you had a box with 10 black balls.  If you choose 3 balls, it is clear that the probability they are all black is 1.  But your method gives $10/10+9/9+8/8=3.$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**.  If you did the same thing for white balls you would get
$$\frac{7}{10}+\frac69+\frac58\ ,$$
which cannot be right as it is bigger than $1$.  Can you see how you have to amend this answer, and your answer too?

Comment: is that why then it should be (7/10)(6/9)(⅝) instead of adding them?

Comment: @user180069 That's right.  As you are drawing one ball **and** then a second **and** then a third, you have to multiply the probabilities.  If you were performing one action **or** another then (under suitable conditions) you would add the probabilities.

Comment: does that mean that the probabilities are dependent?

Comment: In this problem it is a case of conditional probabilities: the factor $2/9$ is the probability that the second draw is black, **given** that the first is black, and we have the formula$$P(A\ \hbox{and}\ B)=P(A)\,P(B\ \hbox{given}\ A)\ .$$It is possible that you have not yet been formally introduced to conditional probabilities.

Comment: @user180069 You have asked 20 questions and never accepted an answer.  Have you never found an answer useful?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a rule of thumb you can use for questions like these:

And means multiply, Or means add.

In the context of your problem, you need to know the probability that ball 1 is black, AND ball 2 is black, AND ball three is black. Hence, you multiply your quantities.

If you have a question like "What is the probability that you pull out a black ball or a white ball?" Then your answer would be $$\frac{3}{10}+\frac{7}{10}$$

Comment: Thank you that helps a lot